# React Native & Firebase: How do I get JSX components to render from a fetched Firebase database of items?

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, lodash, jsx

I am new to React Native and Firebase, this is probably easy but I can't figure out what's wrong.  I'm trying to:

(1) Fetch a list of items from my Firebase database, convert the snapshot.val() that Firebase returns into an array (DONE)

(2) Filter that array for when each object has a specific color (DONE)

(3) Send that filtered array of objects to a function that renders a JSX component to the screen (NOT WORKING)

PROBLEM - The console.log above the return() statement in renderItems() tells me that I am getting the data that I need to be there correctly, but for whatever reason, the JSX  components are not rendering to the screen.  I feel like there is something simple I am missing, but I just can't figure out what.  Please help!

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import _ from 'lodash';
import firebase from 'firebase';
import Item from './Item';

class ItemList extends Component {

  getItemsByColor(color) {
    const itemsRef = firebase.database().ref('/items/');
      itemsRef.once('value').then((snapshot) => {
        const filteredItems = _.filter(snapshot.val(), item => {
          return item.color === color;
        });
        this.renderItems(filteredItems);
      }, (error) => {
        // The Promise was rejected.
        console.error(error);
      });
    }

  renderItems(filteredItems) {
    filteredItems.map((item) => {
      console.log(item.name);
      return <Item name={item.name} color={item.color} />;
    });
  }

  render() {
  return (
    <ScrollView style={{ backgroundColor: '#333', flex: 1 }}>
      {this.getItemsByColor('blue')}
    </ScrollView>
  );

}

}

export default ItemList;
```

Answer (score 1):

Within `renderItems()` you are returning each `<Item/>` to the map function, but are not then returning the result of the function afterwards. Try including another `return` like so:

```
renderItems(filteredItems) {
  return filteredItems.map((item) => {
    console.log(item.name);
    return <Item name={item.name} color={item.color} />;
  });
}
```

You may need to then put in a couple more `return` statements in `getItemsByColor()` as well so that the array of `<Item/>`'s is returned to the function call within `render()`.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but it doesn't seem to be working - the problem seems to be that JSX for some reason won't return from the .once()...then().  Perhaps there is something I'm not understanding with async calls?  Should I be using state somehow to do this?  I've tried but it keeps running setState a million times and getting an error.

Comment: @MaxBrody you don't want to use setState to update the data, I had a similar problem. I'm using functional React components so I used useState() to initialize the state and useEffect() to update it. I believe in a class component you use componentDidMount() and componentShouldUpdate to set and update state.